# TemplateRenderer returning null (Vaadin Flow / 14.1)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

For one of the columns in my `Grid` i use a `TemplateRenderer` (an icon is shown to give a hint about a **possible** issue with this row):

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<T>of("<iron-icon icon='[[item.icon.name]]' title='[[item.icon.tooltip]]' style='width: 1em;'></iron-icon>")
    .withProperty("icon", item -> StatusHint.of(item))
    ...
    ;
```

For some items, this template is not relevant (there are no issues), so property "icon" is `null`. The result is this HTML: `<iron-icon style="width: 1em;" title="undefined"></iron-icon>`.
Also note that the 'icon' attribute is not shown and the title attribute is undefined?!

Although the browser does not show anything, the clueless HTML code is ugly imho (do not know if there are also performance penalties).

An empty cell or `<div></div>` looks much better.

How do i accomplish this? The API does not give me any hints.

Comment: I think null is not allowed, but you can return empty div for example.

Comment: @TatuLund I updated my question to be more clear about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit elaborate, but you can use Polymer's `dom-if` templates to create conditional subtemplates for cases where you can't just bind a property. Here's an example that prints "even" or "odd" depending on whether a Person's age is even or odd:

```
grid.addColumn(
      TemplateRenderer.<Person>of(
      "<template is='dom-if' if='[[item.even]]'><b>even</b></template><template is='dom-if' if='[[!item.even]]'><i>odd</i></template>"
      ).withProperty("even", p -> {
            int age = p.getAge();
            return age % 2 == 0;
      }))
      .setHeader("Is age even or odd?");
```

Comment: Works exactly as I hoped. Or even better, an empty <div> element is not needed.